# WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, mysql-connector, wildfly-27

I am trying to deploy my application after change my persistence.xml but I am receiving errors relative to my persistence.

I do the test connection to my MySQL DB in HAL Management Console and the test is made as success.

persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="itcmedbr_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_medical?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc..password" value="root"/>
      <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

definition of datasource and driver in standalone:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_medical</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource> 

<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

error log:

```
08:48:34,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\Users\Ilo Gabriel\eclipse-workspace\wildfly-27.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\ac\a7e4b6ad429643a5813552677f49ab30f6fdb9\content
08:48:34,188 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/itcmedbr' from server 'default-server'
08:48:34,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 218) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
08:48:34,393 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 218) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@5a4ec8bd
08:48:34,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 218) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
08:48:35,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment itcmedbr.war (runtime-name: itcmedbr.war) in 1116ms
08:48:35,254 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "itcmedbr.war" (runtime-name: "itcmedbr.war")
08:48:48,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for itcmedbr_PU
08:48:48,840 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JIPIORMV6020260: Second level cache enabled for itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU
08:48:48,880 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 218) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller'
08:48:49,127 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment itcmedbr.war
08:48:49,502 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYTRACEXT0012: No Jaeger endpoint or sender-binding configured. Installing a no-op sender
08:48:49,507 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-6) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
08:48:49,509 INFO  [org.wildfly.microprofile.opentracing.smallrye] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYTRAC0001: Tracer initialized: JaegerTracer(version=Java-1.6.0, serviceName=itcmedbr.war, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=NoopSender(), closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=DESKTOP-MOJECP9, jaeger.version=Java-1.6.0, ip=192.168.100.185}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
08:48:49,723 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JIPIORMV6020260: Second level cache enabled for itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU
08:48:49,949 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS]"
    ]
}
08:48:49,951 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS]"
    ]
}
08:48:50,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment itcmedbr.war (runtime-name: itcmedbr.war) in 645ms
08:48:50,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "itcmedbr.war" (runtime-name: "itcmedbr.war")
08:48:50,600 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0014: Replacement of deployment "itcmedbr.war" by deployment "itcmedbr.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.java:MySqlDS]"
    ]
}
08:49:04,360 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for itcmedbr_PU
08:49:05,174 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JIPIORMV6020260: Second level cache enabled for itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU
08:49:05,210 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 218) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller'
08:49:05,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
08:49:05,268 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: itcmedbr_PU]
08:49:05,295 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
08:49:07,622 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment itcmedbr.war
08:49:07,922 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYTRACEXT0012: No Jaeger endpoint or sender-binding configured. Installing a no-op sender
08:49:07,931 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-8) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
08:49:07,932 INFO  [org.wildfly.microprofile.opentracing.smallrye] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYTRAC0001: Tracer initialized: JaegerTracer(version=Java-1.6.0, serviceName=itcmedbr.war, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=NoopSender(), closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=DESKTOP-MOJECP9, jaeger.version=Java-1.6.0, ip=192.168.100.185}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
08:49:08,081 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JIPIORMV6020260: Second level cache enabled for itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU
08:49:08,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
08:49:08,266 INFO  [SQL dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
08:49:08,278 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 245) Envers integration enabled? : true
08:49:10,084 INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 286) Inicializando Mojarra 4.0.0.SP01 para o contexto '/itcmedbr'
08:49:11,832 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 286) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/itcmedbr' for server 'default-server'
08:49:11,974 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\Users\Ilo Gabriel\eclipse-workspace\wildfly-27.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\ac\a7e4b6ad429643a5813552677f49ab30f6fdb9\content
```

I appreciate any assistance.
Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

After change persistence.xml:

from: java:MySqlDS
to: java:jboss/MySqlDS

the problem was solved.

My IDE Eclipse carried me to error, when I write in my persistence correct way the eclipse underlines the word jboss in red and when I point to word eclipse show that "The word 'jboss' is not correctly spelled". Now I doing the deploy of my application.
Thanks guys.